# Do video cables (DVI, VGA) exist that do not need to be screwed in?

Tags: vga, cable

Are there 15pin VGA cables that don't have a screw connection on one end?

What are they called?

Comment: You know that you don't have to actually screw in the screws, right?

Comment: Because they are legacy connections.  The newer standards don't screw in at all.

Comment: @Ramhound DisplayPort has a locking mechanism though. HDMI fits so snugly (usually) that they require some force to plug in/pull out. It's all about the cable being fixed secure enough that it won't accidentally come loose or have a bad contact. With the cable being fairly thick and/or stiff that is something video-cables are prone to.

Comment: @Tonny - Which is exactly my point.  Times were changed design flaws were fixed.  We don't have to deal with stuck pins in the future because those decisions were made.  **The title of this question, and the content itself, changed by the way since I originally made that comment.**

Comment: @ramhound I consider the locking mechanism of DisplayPort (those barbs) a design-flaw too. Plenty of people don't know that they are there. Others just don't have enough power in their fingertips to be able to press the release-latch (often it takes a large amount of pressure). I see a lot of broken DP cables: People pull on the cable instead and break the wiring in the connector. Even yank the cable completely out of the connector. Besides that: Those barbs are often sharp enough to scratch your hand if you happen to grab a cable by the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they exists, but they are quite rare.
I've only seen two of them in the last 30 years.
One around 1990 connecting an Amiga computer to a CRT monitor and a cable (not detachable) on a Philips 17" LCD monitor some 5 years ago (monitor was older than that actually).

AFAIK they don't have a specific name. They are just called VGA cables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know you don't have to use the screws. The thing is the screws make the plug heavier, and therefore more prone to falling out. Anyway I figured a way to get around it and also keep the plug firmly in place. I bought a product called "sugru". It's a self-setting rubber that I placed around the plug and on my PC(not where the pins are). You let it cure over night and presto the plug stays put. It's flexible, so it won't crack or anything. I bought it at Maplin, for £6.50! Great stuff and I can think of at least 10 other projects I can use it on. Check it out...